# I cant't copy/clone html element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, clone, element

I can't clone/copy element in DOM.

My code HTML:

```
<section class="_col-12 flexbox flex-column" id="580">
  <article class="flat-White">
  <img src="https://www.iana.org/_img/2013.1/rir-map.svg" class="campoNoticia img-fluid">
  <div class="campoNoticia p1em">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Parrafe</p>
   </div>
  </article>
</section>
<article>Article area</article>
```

My jQuery Code:

```
$(document).on("click",".campoNoticia", function(evt) {
    var $imgRute = $(this).closest('section').find('img').html();
    $("article").append($imgRute);
});
```

My jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/yt2hbrdn/24/

Comment: What's `.find('img').html()` supposed to select? Images don't contain HTML. What element do you want to clone?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? img doesn't have html. It has source attribute. But again what are you trying to copy?

Comment: I need to copy/clone img tag, example: <img src="all" class="all" />

Comment: And then do what with it? Append it to the article after the one you click on?

Comment: Exact. I need that.

Comment: I need to copy the img tag (all todo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `.html()` will return the HTML inside the element on which it is called.

For example, consider the following code:

```
<div id="test"> Test HTML <div>
```

And the JS:

```
// This will return the inner HTML content of the div
$("#test").html(); // Test HTML
```

As mentioned above, it will **not** return the element. It will only return it's inner HTML.

In your case, it's the `img` element and as you might already know, there is nothing to put inside the `img` element ever i.e. you never do something like this:

```
<!-- This is not valid -->
<img src="something"> Image </img>
```

So, when you do this `var $imgRute = $(this).closest('section').find('img').html();` the value of `$imgRute` will be an empty string and not the `img` element itself.

I guess you want to do `.clone()` instead of `.html()`.

Here's what the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) says about `.clone()`:

> The .clone() method performs a deepcopy of the set of matched elements, meaning that it copies the matched elements as well as all of their descendant elements and text nodes.

So, if you want to clone the `img` element, your code will be as follows:

```
$(document).on("click", ".campoNoticia", function(evt) { 
    var $imgRute = $(this).closest('section').find('img').clone(); 
    $("article").append($imgRute); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to clone the img element, you can just remove the .html() and you will append a clone of the img element.

```
$(document).on("click",".campoNoticia", function(evt) {
    var $imgRute = $(this).closest('section').find('img');
    $("article").append($imgRute);
});
```

I'm not 100% clear that this is what you really want, but it does what you describe in your question.

Note: this will only copy the selected element, it will not deep clone any child elements (non-existent in this example code). So to deep clone, you do need to use `clone()` as the other answers mention.

Comment: This will not clone it. It will remove it first from the `section` element and then add it to `article` element.

Comment: @tarik thansk for answer.

Comment: @sanketd617 quite right, clone is needed to deep clone the object. But it will also not remove it from the parent location since this object contains no html, but just place a copy of the currently selected object in the new node.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the **clone** method

```
$(document).on("click",".campoNoticia", function(evt) {
   var $imgRute = $(this).closest('section').find('img').clone();
   $("article").append($imgRute);
});
```

Comment: God Job @KusokBanana

Answer (score 0):

To copy the image being clicked on and append it to the next article, you can use

```
$(document).on("click", ".campoNoticia", function(evt) {
  var $imgRute = $(this).attr('src');
  $(this).closest('section').next("article").append('<img src="' + $imgRute + '">');
});
```

This get's the src attribute of the image, then searches for the next article element and appends a copy.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".campoNoticia", function(evt) {
  var $imgRute = $(this).attr('src');
  $(this).closest('section').next("article").append('<img src="' + $imgRute + '">');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="_col-12 flexbox flex-column" id="580">
  <article class="flat-White">
    <img src="https://www.iana.org/_img/2013.1/rir-map.svg" class="campoNoticia img-fluid">
    <div class="campoNoticia p1em">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Parrafe</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
<article>Article Área</article>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for help me.